# How do you run?

Tags: ufc-undisputed-2010

For some reason I can't do it.

Comment: for which console?

Comment: @corroded xbox360 or ps3, I think controles are almost the same. I'm not asking about running strikes, but just running. I saw people doing that.

Comment: some more details?

Comment: @Drake like? Just asking how to run, as opposed to walking. *[edited by Oak]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press down on the thumb-stick while you are pushing it in the direction.  This is a similar mechanic to Modern Warfare (if you've played that).